# How to select pairs of rows from a table in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE video_segments (
        video_id TEXT,
        segment_num INTEGER,
        data BLOB
    )
```

I want to select 100 pairs of rows from the table, such that each pair contains 2 segments from the same video, and no 2 pairs are from the same video.

What would be the best query for this?

I tried doing:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT video_id
  FROM video_segments
  GROUP BY video_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)
SELECT *
FROM video_segments
WHERE video_id IN (
  SELECT video_id
  FROM CTE
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
  LIMIT 100
)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 200;
```

but this did not work because sometimes there would be 0 rows with a given video id, and sometimes there would be more than 2 rows with a video id.

Sampled data:

```
video_id|segment_num|data|
foo      0            <bin>
foo      1            <bin>
foo      2            <bin>
foo      3            <bin>
bar      0            <bin>
bar      1            <bin>
baz      0            <bin>
baz      1            <bin>
baz      2            <bin>
```

Lets say I wanted to select 3 random pairs. A valid result might be:

```
foo 0 <bin>
foo 2 <bin>
bar 0 <bin>
bar 1 <bin>
baz 0 <bin>
baz 2 <bin>
```

since results should be random. The result should be different each time.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas; added sample data to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wTAXQWyT)

1. Assume vid <= 10 are the videos chosen and
2. We wish to select 2 sid's per selected vid.
3. Randomly assign a row number to each sid within each vid separately.
4. Then pick the first 2 row numbers (ord < 3) for each of those vids

Note: The first recursive CTE term is only to create test data for segments.

```sql
WITH segments (sid, vid) AS (
        SELECT 0  , 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT sid+1, 1 + (sid+1)/10 FROM segments WHERE sid < 100
     )
   , cte1 AS (
        SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY vid ORDER BY random()) AS ord
          FROM segments AS t
         WHERE vid <= 10
     )
SELECT * FROM cte1
 WHERE ord < 3
 ORDER BY vid, ord
;
```

Now applying that to your schema and initial logic, we have something like this:

[The updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PkwpBeix)

```sql
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT video_id
        FROM video_segments
       GROUP BY video_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
     )
   , cte1 AS (
      SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY video_id ORDER BY random()) AS ord
        FROM video_segments
       WHERE video_id IN (
                SELECT video_id
                  FROM cte
                 ORDER BY RANDOM()
                 LIMIT 100
             )
     )
SELECT * FROM cte1
 WHERE ord < 3
 ORDER BY video_id, ord
;
```

[Fiddle updated with the new data](https://dbfiddle.uk/whIUfuy9)

Result 1:

| video_id | segment_num | data | ord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bar | 1 | null | 1 |
| bar | 0 | null | 2 |
| baz | 0 | null | 1 |
| baz | 2 | null | 2 |
| foo | 1 | null | 1 |
| foo | 0 | null | 2 |

Result 2:

| video_id | segment_num | data | ord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bar | 1 | null | 1 |
| bar | 0 | null | 2 |
| baz | 1 | null | 1 |
| baz | 0 | null | 2 |
| foo | 2 | null | 1 |
| foo | 3 | null | 2 |

etc.

The larger set of data generated in the first fiddle test case shows the random behavior a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` with random ordering:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY video_id ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY video_id) cnt
  FROM video_segments
)  
SELECT video_id, segment_num, data  
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >= 2 AND rn <= 2
ORDER BY video_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qglXwP_X).

Comment: This solution is conceptually more simple, but alas it requires reading the entire DB into memory (the very expensive `data` column), so I think the other solution is preferable

Comment: @Foobar why do you think that the other solution does not read the entire table in memory? Didn't you notice `SELECT *`? You can compare the execution plans of the 3 queries here: https://dbfiddle.uk/GOt9cJcM, https://dbfiddle.uk/6pURcqtF and https://dbfiddle.uk/j1_35Slh

Comment: maybe I am incorrect but it seemed like w/ the other solution, the `select *` was followed by a `where` clause, which would lower the number of rows that are actually selected.